# Help to identify SMD RF Connector

Tags: rf, connector, surface-mount

I have a SmartPill DataRecorder with an SMD antenna connector inside (434MHz antenna.)

This is a photo of the SMD RF connector that I’m trying to identify:

[image]

Frontview:

[image]

Side view:

[image: side view]

I tried to connect a 434MHz antenna with a UFL pigtail, but the pigtail of the antenna is too tiny for the SMD connector of the data receiver.
To me (but I’m not sure,) seems to be the same type of connector as the one on the antenna (U.FL (UMCC), IPEXMHF1), but bigger.

Can anyone help me identify the SMD RF connector and the relative pigtail mate?

The diameter of the connector is about 3 millimeters.

Comment: I think it's an SMA connector, but I'm not confident enough to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SMB Connectors

https://www.rosenberger.com/product/smb/

(its not SMA - SMA has a screwcap...)

---

you find dimensions here
https://www.rosenberger.com/fileadmin/content/headquarter/Products_Services/COM/SMB/59-000-000_TD_01.pdf